# i want capture and upload thumbnail from html5 video tag

Tags: html, video, video-thumbnails

I want capture and upload thumbnail from html5 video tag,

here is my code

```
    var w = 135;//video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
    var h = 101;//video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(_video, 0, 0, w, h);
    canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"); 
    var blob =  canvas.msToBlob();
```

I got this exception **"Object # has no method 'msToBlob'"** in chrome browser .
can anyone help, what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the toBlob method is not supported by chrome yet. I checked the nightly builds and cannot see it.

It was discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83103&q=toblob&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS) for a while but nothing came off it, and firefox are still waiting for the case to be better defined.

So in short chrome doesn't support this yet, and I think its only really supported in ie9 and up so prob best not to use it on production sites yet.

Other suggestions if you are trying to store a screen grab off a canvas is to maby explore using canvas.toDataURL(); and then storing it as base64.

Sorry it wasn't a better result for you

To see updates in Chrome check:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587

Comment: sorry can you clarify by what you mean by it also does not work on other browsers are you still talking about toBlob or toDataUrl

Comment: actually, I want to upload video to my server from mobile throw html5,user select video file and press upload button .

I am using mstoBlob, but I got same error,

Answer (score 0):

The `ms` stands for Microsoft, so `msToBlob` would only be available in IE. Other browsers (once supported) would probably prefix it as well (`webkitToBlob`) and eventually switch to an unprefixed version (`toBlob`)

Even if you checked for support with various prefixes, support is still currently limited. 
Instead, you can use `toDataURL` which returns a base64 encoded URI which you can use as the src attribute of an img element:

```
var b64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
//later... 
thumbnailImg.src = b64;
```